# How to hide logic inside of a method but keep method name with proguard

Tags: java, obfuscation, android-proguard

I'm developing an AAR library for an Android application. I'm trying to use Proguard to keep a certain class visible but I only want to show the method names and not the actual logic inside of the method. In other words, I want clients to be able to call the methods and look at the parameters of the method but not actually look at the content inside of it. I'm currently using the "[typical library example](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/manual/examples.html#library)" from the proguard manual but I am showing all public classes including the logic inside of the methods which is not what I want. I kind of suspect I am asking a very noob questions so I apologize for it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for control flow obfuscation, which is not a feature that ProGuard offers. Some commercial Java/Android obfuscation products such as DashO and DexGuard do support control flow obfuscation. I don't know of any free Java/Android obfuscators that offer control flow obfuscation.

Full disclosure: I work at PreEmptive Solutions, the company that produces DashO.

Comment: @Joel There is another tool named "Allatori". That offers control flow and other good features, however paid. Here is the link : http://www.allatori.com